# underlying provider failed on open

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Делаю приложение с Entity FrameWork.
Если запускать из VS всё работает, если откомпилиные файлы, тоже всё ок, но если публиковать, то выскакивает Выше названное исключение.

Коннекшн стринг:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Contractor_DataBase.Properties.Settings.ContractorContextConnection"
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Contractor_DataBase.DataModels.ContractorContext;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Contractors.mdf"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Также пробовал кучу решений предложенных гуглом и по смене строки подключения, и по переписке конструктора контекста базы данных, а именно:

```
public ContractorContext()
{
    Database.CreateIfNotExists();
    Database.SetInitializer<ContractorContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ContractorContext>());
    Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

В конечном итоге хотелось бы, что бы ентити фраймворк использовал мдф файл как БД.

Comment: Скажите, а куда Вы публикуете? Когда исключение падает? У Вас есть конфигурационныцй файл для выбранной конфигурации? Имеются ли каталоги в месте, куда публикуете?

Answer (score 1):

Пользователь из под которого запускается ваше опубликованное приложение не имеет необходимых прав доступа для подключения к базе.

Для того, что бы это исправить, вы можете добавить в строку подключения следующий параметр:

```
user instance=True
```